# Exposing structs and enums in whole solution

Tags: vb.net, dll, enums, global-variables, public

This is my environment. I have:

"VB.NET solution 1" with:

- "Windows Form Project" (initial project)
- Class Library 1 Solution" 
  "Windows Form Project" is referencing "Class Library Project 1"

"Class Library 1 Solution" contains:

- "Class Library 1 Project"
- "Class Library 2 Project"

"Class Library 1 Project" is exposing as global "Enum 1 Type".

"Class Library 1 Project" is referencing "Class Library 2 Project"

In "Class Library 2 Project" are declared enums in a public module, for example "Enum 2 Type". The goal for me is declare all enums that I need here and use them in whole application.

Namespace for both Class Library Projects is the same (ex. Namespace Common)

Now, from "Class Library 1 Project" I can declare a var of "Enum 2 Type".

From "Windows Form Project" I can declare a var of "Enum 1 Type", but
from "Windows Form Project" I can't declare a var of "Enum 2 Type".

Which is the best strategy for expose "Enum 2 Type" in"VB.NET solution 1" considering:

- I want to declare all enums one time and share them in whole application.
- I need to use in "Class Library 1 Project" and "Windows Form Project".
- I don't want to reference "Class Library 2 Project" in "Windows Form Project".
- I want to reference "Class Library 1 Project" in "Windows Form Project" and so, I could reference "Enum 2 Type".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I don't want to reference "Class Library 2 Project" in "Windows Form Project"` but that is where Enum2 is defined

Comment: No, Plutonix. I try to explain better:  "Enum 2 Type" is defined in "Class Library 2 Project", "Class Library 2 Project" is referenced from "Class Library 1 Project" and "Class Library 1 Project" is referenced from "Windows Form Project". I don't want to reference "Class Library 2 Project" from "Windows Form Project". I want to reference  "Class Library 1 Project" in "Windows Form Project" -as is- and then, I could reference "Enum 2 Type" from "Windows Form Project" and from  "Class Library 1 Project". I hope I explained better.

Comment: They dont pass thru like you seem to think.  Just because CL1 is using CL2 and WinApp1 is using CL1 doesnt mean that WinApp1 can see anything in CL2

Comment: Thanks again. I think so. Then what would be the best strategy to achieve it?